# vim (vim copy-buffer not identical to clipboard-buffer very annoying)

Tags: vim, buffer, clipboard, vi

I use copy and paste a lot in vim, and I have "set clipboard=unnamed" to mirror the vim buffer to the cut/paste buffer; however, I've noticed when copying from the vim buffer, when pasting back into a vim command, it will submit the command (as if a CR or LF was being added to my Pastebin) but this doesn't happen if I use my mouse right click copy/paste (no additional LF/CR).  For example I use visual block to select text, yy to copy, then :%s/ (to replace text) but when I paste it will submit it, but only if I use vim to copy the text the first place not X buffer.  I really hate reaching for my mouse, please help!  Also, I should note I'm on a mac, but I don't think it matters much, vim version 7.4

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit difficult to understand what the issue you are having is but as I understand it you want to copy some text from a buffer and paste it into your command, without causing it to be executed right away.

What I think you want to be doing instead of using your mouse to paste the content into the command is to use `<ctrl-r>`, see `:help i_CTRL-R`, which will allow you to paste the content of the register into the command without using the mouse, and without interpreting the newlines (instead they will appear as `^M`).

E.g. if you type  `yy:%s/<CTRL-R>+` you should see `:%s/LINE-YOU-YANKED^M` in the command.

Alternatively you can use a command that doesn't put a newline in the buffer like `yy` does. Try `y$` or `^y$`.

Comment: YES! thanks! CTRL-R+ very sexy!  It still has the control-character but thats no biggie.   I didn't realize yank added a line feed by default (and X gui copy/cut doesn't) . Thank you very much! Seriously you must be a vim god, i was having difficulty even explaining what the issue was... lol

Comment: Also the other commands solve my issue too! However, is there a way not to add a line feed when using visual block & yank? (obviously the CTRL-R+ command can work)

Comment: Are you using visual, visual-line or visual-block mode or visual mode? (see `:help Visual` for an explanation of the difference)

Answer (score 0):

brettanomyces as answered it completely actually, i've been playing with it for a little while, and when using visual block, I can use CTRL-R+ to paste into the buffer into the command field.  If I want to copy an entire line I can use ^y$, so i don't get line-feeds, this works perfectly.